# Adjust y value of UITableView on Story Board programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I have a UITableView that is on my story board. I would like to adjust the y value of it in the viewDidLoad programmatically based on other information. I cannot seem to get it. I feel like I am missing something quite simple. I have tried all of the following:

```
CGRect myFrame = tableView.frame;
[self->tableView removeFromSuperview];
myFrame.origin.y = myLabel.frame.origin.y+21;
tableView.frame = myFrame;
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

And:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, myLabel.frame.origin.y+21, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height);
```

And:

```
[tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, myLabel.frame.origin.y+21, tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height)];
```

And Finally:

```
CGRect myFrame = tableView.frame;
myFrame.origin.y = myLabel.frame.origin.y + 21;
tableView.frame = myFrame;
```

I have found those snippets of code from other stack questions that are similar to mine. None of them have worked for me. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why is it so complicated? why do you removeFromSuperview? did you consider autolayout idea?

Comment: I am just trying multiple ways of doing it. All of those were on different questions. As you can see none of them have worked @heximal. If you know how to solve the problem, could you post an answer?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? If so what constraints have you set on your tableView?

Comment: I am not using auto layout @beyowulf. All other elements of the view are programmatically created except for the tableview. The reasoning for this is so I can set up the custom cell and constraints on the cell's label much easier using storyboard. I figured there had to be an easy way to adjust the tableview's frame in the code after I placed it on the storyboard

Comment: Have you tried saying `self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;` before setting it's frame?

Comment: No. I will try that @beyowulf

Comment: That worked thanks much. Put that into an answer and i will select it as correct @beyowulf

Comment: did you setup the IBOutlet from storyboard tableview to your .m module?

Answer (score 0):

**I think you not set Autoresizingmask**

Use below code

```
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES
```